# Can't install Python package located in private Nexus repo on docker build

Tags: python, docker, nexus, pypi

I have a private PyPi registry using Nexus. I can publish/install from my host machine without any problems (my personal packages as well as common packages via PyPi nexus proxy). When I try to build a docker image using Dockerfile it allows me to install neither my own packages nor public through the nexus proxy registry (but I still can install public packages from common public registry https://pypi.org/).

**Dockerfile (part)**

```
RUN pypy3 -m pip install --index-url https://username:password@host/repository/pypi-proxy/ flask
RUN pypy3 -m pip install --index-url https://username:password@host/repository/pypi-private/ my
```

**Error**

```
Collecting flask
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flask (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for flask
```

I saw issues with DNS but I can install from `https://pypi.org/` so its not the case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

URLs specified in `index-url` variable were repository URLs not index URLs.
Per https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/PyPI+Repositories#PyPIRepositories-ConfiguringPyPIClientTools, index URLs seem to end in `/simple`.